# Advanced search is not functional for two fields

Tags: php, yii

I am stuck  with an issue regarding searching functionality.I am using `PHP` and `Yii framework`. I have a search option in my grid view which has 5 fields with drop down menu, 3 field in the search form are working only two fields are not working....I don't know why..I have written a search function in my model.

Model:

```
 public function searchByManager($id)
    {
        $User =new User;
        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
        $criteria->with=array('user');
        $criteria->condition = "user.supervisor_id = $id";
        $criteria->compare('user_id',$this->user_id);
        $criteria->compare('job_title_id',$this->job_title_id);
        $criteria->compare('cv_type',$this->cv_type,false);
        $criteria->compare('review_status',$this->review_status,true);
        $criteria->compare('is_current',$this->is_current,true);
        $criteria->addInCondition("is_current", array("yes"));
        //$criteria->condition = "cv_upload.is_current = yes";
        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
            'sort'=>array(
            'defaultOrder'=>'upload_date DESC'
            )
        ));
    }
```

`user_id` and `job_title_id` these two fields are not working...when I search by them it shows an error something like this:

> CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[23000]:
>   Integrity constraint violation

Can anyone please help me out.

Comment: Have you tried 't.user_id' and 't.job_title_id' in your  query? 
Because may be its conflict with 'user' table field.

Comment: @shopnil are you searching by id or by name ?

Comment: which fields not working?

Comment: You need to add table alias using `$criteria->alias = 'tableName t';`

Comment: @Criesto i am searching by id...

Comment: @Dharmesh Goswami I have tried table name.user_id or job_title_id in my query...but it shows error..

Comment: @shopnil do you add this fields to `rules()` method?

Comment: @gamitg user name and job title are coming from user table and job_title table..Can please explain more clear regarding your suggestion...

Comment: which fields are common in both table?

Comment: yes i add the fields in the rules in the model... @SiZE

Comment: user_id and job_title_id are common @gamitg

Comment: I mean that same name field in both table..

Comment: yes same name for both table user_id and job_title_id....@gamitg